# NewRelic monitoring, 'This server is no longer reporting'

Tags: newrelic

We have been running the free version of New Relic on a Windows 2012 Server for around a week. It was reporting fine (in the iPhone app and website).

2 days ago it stopped. The service is running fine on the server - and we have tried restarting the service - all has no effect.

What is the problem / how can we trouble shoot it?

Comment: Is it the server monitor or the agent that isn't running? Also what environment are you running your website in (.NET, PHP, etc.)?

Comment: This resolved itself after I increased the logging level & contacted their support - appeared to be a problem their end.